# Dynamic tables in jsp using Spring framework

Tags: json, spring, dynamic-tables

I am working in Spring MVC. These is the scenario..

1. I select a value from dropdown box and click a button on jsp .
2. An event is triggered using javascript function.
3. Based on input,some database queries are executed , records  are retrieved and
   data is set into JSON Object in controller class.
4. How can I populate this JSON Object into the same jsp using table .?
5. Can I populate the same in a new tab.?

If you suggest a solution , then it would be highly helpful for me and my friends..
Thank you...

Comment: Your question is way too broad for SO. Appropriate questions ask how to overcome a specific programming problem, yours is just a list of requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with JOSN object better option is used JQuery and send request to controller using 
JQuery and get the JSON object and simple print in html code.

another option is generate html code in controller and send as a response and then simple print that response as a html souce of div.
are you getting me?

Comment: Thanks for your time and really appreciate your help. Kind Regards!!!Can you show a small piece of code that is generating html using database records in controller..Thank you..